# Ubuntu 20.04 not getting locked after lid close

Tags: gnome, lockscreen, suspend, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed the latest ubuntu 20.04 and recently noticed a bug that whenever I close my lid the screen only goes blank instead of going into hibernate or suspend.

- I noticed that there is no longer an option in gnome-settings as it was in ubuntu 18.04.
- I have tried changing the values in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.
- I tried changing values in gnome-tweaks.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Could you explain how [hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/) library is involved into your problem?

Comment: I am not referring to the [hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/) library but the hibernate feature of Ubuntu

Comment: Could not reproduce with my install.

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].